# SSRS Performance - Filter property vs WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'd like to know the differences between setting a filtering condition within the query (in the WHERE clause) as opposed to leaving it in the FilterExpression conditions, mainly performance-wise, although I'm also interested in other differences and advantages of using one over the other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering on the WHERE clause will constrain the amount of results that actually make it into your report.   This should be more performant as the report won't have to deal with as much data.

The FilterExpression filters the data that gets to your report.

For smaller resultsets, the results should be negligible.   For larger result sets, use the WHERE clause.

Comment: FilterExpression would limit what's visible in the report and operate on data in-memory.  `WHERE` would work in the RDBMS and limit what is retrieved off disk and into the report engine.

Comment: Filtering is useful where you want to use the same query results in several objects in your report. In this case, it might be (depending on the case) to use a single query and then filter it in the components themselves.

Comment: So if the WHERE clause delivers the best performance, what's the point of using FilterExpressions in datasets? I was expecting SSRS to build a proper query behind the scenes, like ORMs do for example.

Comment: There are occasions where it's a benefit to have more data than you're displaying, for use in calculations, etc.   There are normally workarounds for this.   Most of SSRS is just typical MS; lower the barrier of entry to allow newbs to clear it.  I was one of those newbs once.  Now I cut out the middleman and use iTextSharp (PDF) or EPPlus (Excel) for reports.  First thing my SSRS customers did was export to another format :D